# Generating PDF report in PHP and by using fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am presently working on the Report generation in PHP, which I found fpdf can help me out with the same. I would like to know how to display the current logged-in user details from the database on the pdf generated. Even if you could share with me any specific link pertaining to this.

My code to check if user is logged in

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) 
{ 
$get_name=mysql_query("select * from mep_users where us_email='".$_SESSION['user_logged_in']."'")or die("error appeared"); while($get_nammer=mysql_fetch_array($get_name)) 
{ ?> <?php echo ' | '.$get_nammer['us_name']. " @ My Eye Prescription"; ?> <?php } } ?>
```

This is the query to retrieve the value that is stored in database table mep_user_content. I can see the record in the pdf file pertaining to id 17. But I would like to see the record entered by the user i.e. the new user logging in or the guest user with the respective id. Thanks.

```
$pdf->AddCol('rs',40,'Right Eye');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select rs from mep_user_content where us_id="17"',$prop);
```

Comment: I don't know but, I think fpdf doesn't have function `AddCol` and `Table`. If you work with fpdf, why don't take a look at their website here http://www.fpdf.org ?

Comment: thanks for the reply.... yes I have been referring to fpdf.org website. It shows data retrieval example but I wanted for user entered value to appear on the pdf. i.e.thru session.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing database query with `fpdf`. you need to deal separately whether you need to get database value or guest user value. Store appropriate values in variable and use that variable while generating `PDF` file.

For example,

```
$required_value = "something"; // From database...
```

OR

```
$required_value = "something else"; // From guest user...
```

Now use `$required_value` to place it in your pdf file.

**EDIT:**

```
$sess_id = $_SESSION['user_logged_in'];
$pdf->Table("select rs from mep_user_content where us_id='$sess_id'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: for the sql query used 
$pdf->Table('select rs from mep_user_content where us_id="17"',
retrieves record stored at us_id=17
how to do the same for the current user with user id us_id

Comment: Are you storing `us_id` in session for logged in users?

Comment: well it has been set to Auto.

Comment: the user logs enters prescription details
all values r stored in the database
now in order for the record to appear on the pdf entered by the current user I would like to seek some help in writing SQL
I tried...
$pdf->Table('select rs from mep_user_content where us_id="17"'

Comment: In that case you can simply dump php variable in your query.  `us_id="$us_id"`

Comment: The query `$pdf->Table('select rs from mep_user_content where us_id="17"')` displays stored value of rs entered by user in the database. I would like to request for help in retrieving value of rs entered during the session.
So I tried...
`$pdf->Table('select rs from mep_user_content where us_id='".$_SESSION['user_logged_in']."''` .... kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: using us_id="$us_id" lists down all the ids... 
i want only that particular id which user has logged in during that session

Comment: Well it must work but there seems something going missing out hence it is not clicking thru.

Comment: I would like to share the code...
`<?php
require('mysql_table.php');
class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('mep');

if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']))
    {
        $get_name=mysql_query("select us_name from mep_users where us_email='".$_SESSION['user_logged_in']."'");
        while($pull_name=mysql_fetch_array($get_name))
        {
            $name=$pull_name['us_name'];
        }
    }else
    {
        $name='Guest User';
    }

if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']))
    {
        $sess_id = $_SESSION['user_logged_in'];
  
    }`
contd

Comment: contd...

'$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddCol('rs',20,'Sphere');
$pdf->Table('select * from mep_user_content where us_id="$sess_id"');
$pdf->Output();
?>`
It din output anything.. which means it works only that something is going missing
  So, I tried adding the following lines.... rs is the value entered by the user accessing the page...
    `header('Location:index.php?rs='.$_GET['rs'].'');`

Kindly advise...
Thanks